# Can't add index to innodb table - "table '#sql_...' is full"

Tags: mysql, debian, innodb, ext3

I have a frustrating problem here. I need to add an index to an innodb table which is a few gb in size.

Every time I try this:

```
alter table x add index y;
```

I get

```
Error Code : 1114
The table '#sql-5f87_30' is full
```

I already have innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend so no limits on the tablespace, and I also have innodb_file_per_table = on.

Also, I've tried changing tmpdir to a dir on a partition with 300 gigs of space.

The server is 64bit Debian, with an ext3 filesystem and 7.5GB ram. There are 4 indexes on the table already.

Can anyone shed light on what the problem could be?

Thanks

Rich

Comment: did you check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/full-table.html ?

Comment: yes, I've read through that a few times this morning. I'm on 64bit linux with an ext3 partition, and the filesizes of the tables & ibdata1 are nowhere near 16GB. The table is question is only taking up 3GB. I presume that it's a temp table which it's saying is full

Comment: what memory does your server have?

Comment: How many indexes do you have on the table? MySQL doesn't seem to document what InnoDB's per-table limit is, but says that all the engines support at least 16. Try dropping one of the existing indexes and add this new one temporarily to see if it goes in (and then check if the one you'd dropped won't go in).

Comment: There are only 4 indexes plus the primary key. I'm don't know but I would have thought it can handle more indexes than that?

Comment: Why not locate the file(s) named #sql-5f87_30.* on your system - if you find them you may find that they are in a partition which is full?

Comment: check this post [MySQL Index creation failing on table is full](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68319/mysql-index-creation-failing-on-table-is-full) Hope it helps